# Python openai api chatgpt multi prompt

Tags: python, openai-api

I want to make a list using openai api. But when I say continue the list, it doesn't see the previous list. I added the picture. how can I do it ?
[image]

```
import openai
import os

openai.api_key = "xxxxxx"
model_engine = "gpt-3.5-turbo-0301"


prompt = "dress pattern"
cont_query = "continue"
file_name = prompt + ".txt"

def run_gpt(prompt):
    completions = openai.ChatCompletion.create(
        model=model_engine,
        max_tokens=3800,
        n=2,
        stop=None,
        temperature=0.7,
        messages=[{"role": "user", "content": prompt}]
    )

    message = completions['choices'][0]['message']['content']
    return message.strip()

main_response = run_gpt(prompt)
cont_response = run_gpt(cont_query)


with open(file_name, "w") as file:
    file.write(f"{main_response}\n\n")
    file.write(f"{cont_response}\n\n")
```

Comment: Where exactly are you trying to make a list?

Comment: When I query about "dress pattern" it gives few results.
 When I do the "continue" query, I want it to continue with the previous query.

Comment: Okay, but that has nothing to do with creating a list in python

Comment: I want to do this with python.  Have you had a chance to look at the code I wrote?

Comment: I'm looking at it, and your question asked for a list. Your code creates no actual list objects. Therefore it's not possible to answer your question, as it is unclear. Please [edit] to clarify the problem. You "see previous response" using the `main_response` variable, which you're already using.

Answer (score 0):

In order for ChatGPT to continue the conversation, you need to resubmit the chat history in the "messages" argument. So you will need to maintain the history in order to append "continue" or any other follow up queries.

Here is an example of what your "messages" argument would look like:

```
messages = [{"role": "system", "content": "You are a creative fashion designer."},
              {"role": "user", "content": "List dress pattern ideas"},
              {"role": "assistant", "content": "1. Tunic dress 2. Tea dress 3. Kimono dress..."},
              {"role": "user", "content": "continue"}]
```

(Please note that any included chat history in order to continue a conversation will always count against your token limit)